# How to close open html tags in an php foreach loop

Tags: php, html, loops, menu, foreach

I have this code that produces a horizontal menu in wordpress. However, it produces invalid code because the html tags aren't closed. I have tried adding the closing tags in the loop but seems to mess up the menu bad.

```
foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $tiny_menu_list .= '<option value="'. $menu_item->url .'">'. $menu_item->title .'</option>';
    if( !$menu_item->menu_item_parent ){
        $menu_list .= '<li><div><a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';
            if( count($menu_items) > 1 )
                $menu_list .= '<span>';
            continue;
    }
    $menu_list .= '|<a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';
}
if( count($menu_items) > 1 )
    $menu_list .= '</span>';
$menu_list .= '</div></li></ul>';
```

Here is what the code generates:

```
<li><div><a href="/">Home Page</a>
<span><li><div><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a>
<span>|<a href="/why-us/">Why Us ?</a>|<a href="/why-us/compare/">Compare Us</a>
<li><div><a href="/tour/">Take A Tour</a>
<span>|<a href="/frequently-asked-questions/">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
<li><div><a href="/free-options-videos/">Free Options Videos</a>
<span><li><div><a href="/options-courses/">Options Courses</a>
<span>|<a href="./">Extended Options Course</a>|<a href="/ultimate-options-course/">Ultimate Options Course</a></span></span></div></li></ul>
```

As you can tell, each li & span & div are not closed. Thankfully browsers correct for this, but for the sake of being html5 compliant, could use the help in fixing it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what is the correct HTML you are trying to generate?

Comment: Correct code should have closing tags at the end of each line like: 
    <li><div><a href="/">Home Page</a></div></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not due to html tags, this is happening because you are missing many closing `</div>` and `</li>` .

On formatting the code dumped by your loop it shows up like this:

```
<li>
   <div>
   <a href="/">Home Page</a></li>
   <span>
<li>
   <div>
   <a href="/about-us/">About Us</a>
   <span>|<a href="/why-us/">Why Us ?</a>|<a href="/why-us/compare/">Compare Us</a>
<li>
   <div>
   <a href="/tour/">Take A Tour</a>
   <span>|<a href="/frequently-asked-questions/">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
<li>
   <div>
   <a href="/free-options-videos/">Free Options Videos</a>
   <span>
<li><div><a href="/options-courses/">Options Courses</a>
<span>|<a href="./">Extended Options Course</a>|<a href="/ultimate-options-course/">Ultimate Options Course</a></span></span></div></li></ul>
```

You can check the error by pasting this code in [html validator like this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html)

And it will show you the missing elements.

Comment: Yeah, but I dont know how to edit the PHP loop to fix the issues. You are correct on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try close your tags in the foreach-loop. Maybe like this:

```
$hasChildLinks = false
foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $tiny_menu_list .= '<option value="'. $menu_item->url .'">'. $menu_item->title .'</option>';
    if( !$menu_item->menu_item_parent ){
        $menu_list .= '<li><div><a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';
        if( count($menu_items) > 1 ) {
            $menu_list .= '<span>'
            $hasChildLinks = true;
        } else {
            $menu_list .= '</div></li>';
        }
        continue;
    }
    $menu_list .= '|<a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';
    if( (count($menu_items) > 1) && ($hasChildLinks) ) {
        $menu_list.= '</span>';
    }
}
$menu_list .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: This sorta works, it closes spans with less 2 child menus, but has an issue with 2+ because the span gets closed too soon. The else with </div></li> doesn't seem to work...